# calling parseInt on string in node js returns NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm passing in a Buffer from the client-side using the binaryjs module in node js. This buffer contains a pipe delimited string that I eventually parse on the server.

On the client side I convert a String to a Uint8Array. My String looks something like this:

```
var stringToConvert = 'A_1_22|B_2_33|C_3_44';
```

When this Uint8Array is passed to my server, it's received as a Buffer. I first chunk together the Buffer into an array:

```
var parts = [];
// ...
// as data is received:
parts.push(data);
```

When I have all the data streamed, I convert this array to a String and split by "|":

```
var arrayString = parts.toString().split("|");
```

This gets me the desired array output:

```
arrayString = ['A_1_22', 'B_2_33', 'C_3_33'];
```

I then iterate over this arrayString and split again by "_".

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++)
{
    var thisArray = arrayString[i].split("_");
    // ...
```

The problem occurs when I try to iterate over thisArray to convert the second and third values to ints:

```
var intVal1 = parseInt(thisArray[1]); // returns NaN
var intVal2 = parseInt(thisArray[2]); // returns NaN
console.log(typeof thisArray[1]); // returns string
```

Running the identical code on the client side properly converts the strings to ints. Not sure what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the actual content of `thisArray`? Maybe put breakpoint before the `parseInt` and check for somehow improper strings.

Comment: Can you just console `thisArray` and make sure it contains numeric string?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and the console does show a proper numeric string. As I mentioned, running this identical code on the client side returns the desired int output.

Comment: Have you tried printing out thisArray[1] before you attempt to parse it. You may find that if for whatever reason the string wasn't split as expected it is attempting to parse undefined.

Comment: You should be passing 2 arguments to `parseInt()`: the string to parse, and then the base (10).

Comment: Yes, I've tried console.log(thisArray[1]) which returns 1, and console.log(typeof thisArray[1]) which returns string

Comment: @Pointy I've tried the base 10 as well, i.e. parseInt(thisArray[1], 10) but this also outputs NaN

Comment: Don't just log the strings - log the character codes.  That is, make sure that the first characters in the string are really the correct character codes. Trying your code in Node on my machine works fine. A leading space character (or any other non-digit) would result in a `NaN`.

Comment: Code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5YLfn/1/

Comment: Given your claims, I ran a test on node (windows version 0.6.19  and it works as expected. `var arrayString = ['A_1_22', 'B_2_33', 'C_3_33'];
for(var i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++)
{
    var thisArray = arrayString[i].split("_");
 console.log(parseInt(thisArray[1])); 
}`

Comment: @Pointy I logged the character codes and it seems the Strings contained a bunch of '0' character codes. I wrote a simple clean-up function to strip those out from my string and all seems well. Thanks for the obvious tip, seems like I had tunnel vision.